# How can I get the correct output?

Tags: javascript, math, concatenation

I have this code:

```
      var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
              alert("Your number is the sum of " + theNumber + 10);
```

I notice that Javascript tries to convert the 10 into a string (as expected) and I was wondering what should I change within my code for the output the be the actual sum of the value theNumber(that the user will choose) plus the number 10.

Comment: Create a variable called temp and assign its value as temp = theNumber +10; and use it instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses.

You need to do:

```
alert("Your number is the sum of " + (theNumber + 10));
```

The issue is that it works from left to right, so it sees a string and then converts `theNumber` to a string and then it sees the 10 and converts the 10 to a string. By adding parentheses, you can get it to do the addition first, and then convert into a string.

Comment: Yes, now I understand and it makes sense. Another user wrote to code by changing the order inside the parentheses (but not adding extra ones) and it also woked. So I suppose in this case the order is very important. I am new to Javascript and I still try to get the hang of it :). Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
          alert("Your number is the sum of " + (theNumber + 10));
```

Comment: It worked just fine, thx a lot. I am new to Javascript and this seemed to be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: yeah, very easy but I advise you to study a book of js first if you have not.

Answer (score 0):

Preceding the alert with the transformation to a number ([JavaScript Number() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)) will fill `theNumber` with what is indeed a number:

`var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
alert(theNumber + 10 + " sums to your number");`

Comment: Your code looks pretty much like mine, just the order inside the parentheses is different. How come it works? It is because it works from left to right?

Comment: Its just the way JS parses, as long as its dealing witth numbers, its a number. Once a string comes along, everything its strings (i.e. strings have precedence over numbers.)

Answer (score -1):

```
alert("Your number is the sum of " + (theNumber + parseInt(10)));
```

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

Comment: add a radix for parseint dude. ie9 defaults to base 8.

Comment: Thx for the answer... still haven't got to that function so I am not sure how it works. Yet :).

Comment: basically in javascript everything is string so even you say var  a = 10; It will assume it as a is string so to convert that string value to actual integer you can use parseInt() function that converts it to integer value.